# How to use GitVersion /UpdateAssemblyInfo for changes that haven't been committed yet?

Tags: c#, .net, git, assemblyinfo, gitversion

perhaps there's something that I don't understand when it comes to working with `GitVersion`.

Suppose I am on my main branch, and the latest commit has been tagged, with, say, `1.1.2`.
Now that my build works and that I am ready to release `1.1.3`, I would like to update my `AssemblyInfo` file to match the next release.

However, when I build with `GitVersion.exe /UpdateAssemblyInfo`, it returns the current tag.
How then, can I get my Assembly tagged with the right info? Given that I cannot tag something that I have not committed, I need to commit first, then rerun `GitVersion.exe /UpdateAssemblyInfo`.

My current workaround consists in committing twice then squashing the two commits, but there must be a better way to do this.

Thanks!